# Registering donor while using other payment processors

Tags: contributions, payment-processor

do you have any knowledge on whether it is possible to register a user who is using for payment a processor that isn't listed in official guides?
We receive donations using Paypal but also through Corvus payment gateway, Paycek (for cryptocurrencies) and another that is more "local".

The way I see it, a donor would be able to register on our webpage and through that give a donation using PayPal which should then be registered in his profile but I am unsure if such thing is possible using the other routes because there are no developed plugins in civiCRM ecosystem. I am guessing, that such data will have to be manually added if we don't want to develop a plugin?

The donations are either one-off or recurring.

Any help and/or pointers would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to have the other payments that aren't actually tied to CiviCRM go through the 'pay later' option. Then they would go in with the status of pending pay later. Then in your instructions, you could give the link they would need to use in order to actually pay for it (assuming that you have one to give). Then their information would be in the system and all you would need to do is go in and edit it to complete and input the information regarding when/how they paid.

Comment: seems like a good approach for one-off, not sure it will help with recurring

Comment: Yea, recurring makes things a little more difficult. But with that, the person who does memberships in the org I work with just goes in and manually clicks renew once the person pays via whatever the source is (check, call in, etc).

Comment: Hmm, yeah that seems like the only viable option. In the long run it would probably be a pain and it doesn't offer "streamlined" approach. So I'm guessing that if you want that you should probably work with payment processors that have plugins available for civi if that's possible.

Comment: Yup, we've pretty much tried to just stay with those that have plugins. But they also do some stuff over the phone, by purchase order and check, etc.